# Adding x-frame-Options in web.config return error 500

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, x-frame-options

I added X-frame-Options in my web.config.

This is my web.config

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

After restarting IIS I got 500 error!!!

Can someone help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Modify your `customHeaders` as below:

```
<customHeaders>
  <clear />
  <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
</customHeaders>
```

I suspect that your application is located within a virtual folder, if that's the case then two `web.config` files are processed. First is the global one, the the second time is yours. So you end up having two collection of `customHeaders`.

Blog post [IIS 7: But why do I get a 500.19](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tristank/2013/03/06/iis-7-but-why-do-i-get-a-500-19cannot-add-duplicate-collection-entry-with-0x800700b7/) explains in more details why it is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your location to add CustomHeaders is wrong. Correct location is :

```
  ....
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <requestFiltering>
          <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
               <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
          </verbs>
          </requestFiltering>
       </security>
       <httpProtocol>
              <customHeaders>
                    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW" />
                    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
                    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
              </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <modules>
                <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  ....
```

Other option is Useful for your application security.